# When you shop online or when you are shopping online

Tags: present-tense

I have written this sentence:

> When you shop online, it is a big chance you **buy** something that
>   doesn’t fulfill your expectations.

Is it good or should I use present continuous? I don't know why but present continuous sounds better to me. But from what I have learned, I could use it only if I was online shopping at this specific moment.

Comment: Either sounds normal to me, (American English) but "it is a big chance" should be "there is a big chance"

Comment: I'd also say "you'll buy" rather than "you buy".

Comment: Please see also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this rule. Could you please explained to me why can I use also present continuous, even when the shopping does not happen at this time. Thank you.

Comment: @trenccan I believe it is because you are talking about a hypothetical. The shopping may not be occurring right now, but the sentence talks about something that happens *during the act* of shopping, therefore present continuous.

Comment: You can think of it informally this way: when you are do**ing** something, you do it *during* that 'when' time.

Comment: Note that "... it is a big chance ..." is entirely non-idiomatic.